# Reducing Lagrange Multiplier Problems from Two Constraints to One Constraints

Tags: calculus

I have a general question about Lagrange multiplier problems with two constraints.  If it is possible to isolate for one of the variables in one of the constraints and substitute it into the second constraint equation, then will extremizing the objective function constrained to the "merged" function yield the same result?

Also, is there any method to reduce difficult to solve Lagrange multiplier problems of two or more constraints down?  Thanks!